# jQuery UI Slider ui.value get last digit

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

How do I get ONLY the last digit from the ui.value of a slider that is two digits long (XX).

I tried this but it does not seem to be acceptable?

```
var $lastNumber = ui.value.length-1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var $lastNumber = ui.value % 10;
```

Comment: This works! To clarify, I actually used "ui.value % 10" like this: activeBackground_1 = 'url(images/numbers/10'+ ui.value % 10 +'.png)';

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var sliderVal   = ui.value;
var $lastNumber = sliderVal.toString().charAt(sliderVal.length-1)
```